# Disabling html elements on button click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently using Jquery to manipulate html elements. Currently I am only working with divs, a textarea and two buttons. For this question: I have an admin button `id="adminControl"` which I would like to fire a clickevent that will disable the textearea, button `id="#appendText"` and the div `class="middle-side"`. I try doing the previous through keeping a count on button click `id="adminControl"` but nothing is being disable. I am aware it is possible with input fields but would it be possible with a div? [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uLs3e9qs/5/)

Jquery

```
var clickCount = 0;
$('#adminControl1').click(function (e) {
    clickCount ++;
    if (clickCount == 1){
        $( "#button" ).prop( "disabled", true );
        $( "#divText" ).prop( "disabled", true );
        $( "#adminControl1").value("Enable All");
    } else {
        $( "#button" ).prop( "disabled", false );
        $( "#divText" ).prop( "disabled", false );
        $( "#adminControl1").value("disable All");
        clickCount --;
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="divText" placeholder="Enter Text Here!"></textarea> 
<input type="button" id="appendText" value="Add Div with Text" /><br/>

<div>
    <div class="middle-side empty">
        <h2 class="placeholder-title hidden">Place Inside Here</h2>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="adminArea">
    <h3>Admin Area</h3>
    <input type="button" id="adminControl1" value="Disable All" />
</div>
```

Comment: Please remove one of the two click functions and all the other unrelated code from your fiddle. It should demonstrate the problem in the simplest possible manner.

Comment: What do you mean by disable the div middle-size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey you had a few errors in there:

1. .value() should be val()
2. to toggle the enable and disable, use a mod count and don't decrement the counter
3. remove the duplicate click on the disable button
4. you forgot to close a parenthesis
5. $("#button") should have been $("#appendText")

I updated your `JSFiddle` http://jsfiddle.net/hawaiianchimp/xdfq9hc3/2/

Comment: Ok this makes much more sense. One thing that it has not disable it is the draggable `class="draggaable"`. For example if you click button `appendText` it will create a draggable div. Then when you click the disable button. The user can still drag the div. How can I disable drag for that div?

Comment: use `$(".draggable").draggable("disable");` I've updated the jsfiddle

Comment: Yes I found out with some experimentation and research. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check if one element is disabled and do the following:

```
$('#adminControl1').click(function (e) {

    if(!$("#appendText").prop("disabled")){
        $("#appendText, #divText, .middle-side empty").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#adminControl1").val("Enable All");
    }
    else{
        $("#appendText, #divText, .middle-side empty").prop("disabled", false);
        $("#adminControl1").val("Disabled All");
    }    
});
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uLs3e9qs/19/)

Answer (score 0):

Use val() instead of value(). Here is working code

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
    <html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="" content="">
    </head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var clickCount = 0;
        $().ready(function(e){
            $('#adminControl1').click(function (e) {
        var clickCount= parseInt($("#counter").val());

        $("#counter").val(clickCount+1);
        if (clickCount == 1){
            $( "#button" ).prop( "disabled", true );
            $( "#divText" ).prop( "disabled", true );
            $( "#adminControl1").val("Enable All");
        } else {
            $( "#button" ).prop( "disabled", false );
            $( "#divText" ).prop( "disabled", false );
            $( "#adminControl1").val("disable All");
            clickCount --;
        }
    })
        })


    </script>
    <body>
    <form>
    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="divText" placeholder="Enter Text Here!"></textarea> 
    <input type="button" id="appendText" value="Add Div with Text" /><br/>
    <input type="text" id="counter" value="1" /><br/>

    <div>
        <div class="middle-side empty">
            <h2 class="placeholder-title hidden">Place Inside Here</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="adminArea">
        <h3>Admin Area</h3>
        <input type="button" id="adminControl1" value="Disable All" />
    </div>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```